# #!/bin/bash read if then return to read

Tags: bash, if-statement, return

I want to make a script and after you type first command, I want to be sent back to previous.

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " COMMAND
if [ "$COMMAND" = x ] ; then
    echo " This is command X. "
#Then return to    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " COMMAND

elif [ "$COMMAND" = y ]; then
    echo " This is command y. "
#Then return to    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " COMMAND

elif [ "$COMMAND" = z ]; then
    echo " This is command z"
#Then return to    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " COMMAND

else
    echo " Command not found! "
fi
```

For example if you type x , I want to be possible to type after that y or z. It can be done in same script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the part you want to repeat in a loop, and consider how you'll *exit* from the loop. Here, the `break` command will exit the loop if you enter `q`. Otherwise, after the `if` statement finishes, you'll return to the top of the loop for another round.

```
while true; do
    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z; q]: " COMMAND
    if [ "$COMMAND" = x ] ; then
        echo " This is command X. "        
    elif [ "$COMMAND" = y ]; then
        echo " This is command y. "        
    elif [ "$COMMAND" = z ]; then
        echo " This is command z"
    elif [ "$COMMAND" = q ]; then
        break
    else
        echo " Command not found! "
    fi
done
```

You can clean this up by use a `case` statement instead of big `if` statement. You can execute multiple commands for each choice; the `;;` signals the end of each particular block.

```
while true; do
    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z; q]: " COMMAND
    case $COMMAND in
        x) echo "This is command X."
           ;;
        y) echo "This is command Y."
           ;;
        z) echo "This is command Z."
           ;;
        q) break ;;
    esac
done
```

You can also include a specific test in place of the `true` command, so that the loop itself can check the value of command and terminate, rather than waiting for an explicit `break` command.

```
while [ "$COMMAND" -ne q ]; do
    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z; q]: " COMMAND
    case $COMMAND in
        x) echo "This is command X."
           ;;
        y) echo "This is command Y."
           ;;
        z) echo "This is command Z."
           ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Your comment has helped me. I like more the first option with if.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive function would make the job easy

```
#!/bin/bash
readfun(){
read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " command  # Use lowercase names
[[ "$command" =~ ^[xyz]$ ]] && readfun 
# logical AND ie '&&' terminates the recursion if any character other than x y z is entered
}
readfun #starting point for the script
echo "Command : ${command} not found"
```

Comment: I wouldn't use recursion just to simulate iteration in shell.

Comment: I very much doubt `bash` is optimized for recursion; eventually, you'll run out of room on the stack. Just use a loop.

Comment: @chepner : I doubted that recursive calls are not optimized but i wonder the documentation didn't mention about this.

Comment: Shell languages typically assume a background in procedural languages, where recursion is typically used only to traverse a recursive data structure (which most shell languages lack). Using recursion for any type of repetition is a hallmark of functional programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the whole thing in a never-ending `while` loop:

```
while true
do
    [whatever]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

`while` and `case`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    read -p " Please enter [x ; y ; z]: " COMMAND
    case $COMMAND in
        x) echo " This is command x. "
            ;;
        y) echo " This is command y. "
            ;;
        z) echo " This is command z. "
            ;;
        *) exit 0
            ;;
    esac
done
```

In action:

```
$ bash test.sh
 Please enter [x ; y ; z]: x
 This is command x.
 Please enter [x ; y ; z]: y
 This is command y.
 Please enter [x ; y ; z]: z
 This is command z.
 Please enter [x ; y ; z]: a
$
```